# Cone-Light events

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light

The events Q that occur within the cone of the light cone of an event P, are seen by all observers in the same order. But how can I be mathematically sure that in effect it happen?

Comment: The condition for the order of events to be invariant is that they must have time-like separation, which being contained within the same lightcone does not guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is not formulated very clearly. Two events Q1 and Q2 can be seen by different observers in different order (whether they lay inside of the lightcone of some P or not.)

However, if Q's lay in the future lightcone of P, this will be seen in the same way by all observers! The reason is that Lorentz transformations do not change the sign of $\Delta t$. So it follows $t(Q)>t(P)$ in all reference frames.